# If you update a project, do you need to recompile all projects that reference it?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a few utility projects that other applications I have reference.
For example, I have a MailSender project that has methods in it for sending emails. I add it as a reference when I start a new project, and have those methods available in the new project.

If I update that utility project, do I have to recompile all of the projects that reference it, or can I just drop in the new dll to effect the change? Assume that the signature and name of the methods those projects are referencing stay the same; it's an internal change in the utility project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No need to recompile referencing projects. Just recompile the utility and drop in/replace your new DLL and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I guess instead of asking the question I could have just tried it and seen what happened!!